# Bot command returns multiples times

Tags: discord, discord-jda

```
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e)
   {
      String message = e.getMessage().getContentRaw();
      
          if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("!hi")) {
             
              e.getChannel().sendMessage("Hi").queue();
          }
          if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("!hello")) {
              e.getChannel().sendMessage("Hello").queue();
          }
   }
```

When I open up my EclipseIDE, run the code, and send a command(!hi, for example) to Discord, it prints normally at first. However, for some reason, it stacks up the message, eventually. What I mean by this is this:

[image]

So now whenever I send a command, it replies multiple times. I don't know if it's a server problem, but it just stacks up. The code I did for the command is shown above. Is there a solution on how to go around this problem? All I did in my 'Main.java' class is add an event listener once for this method's class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot unusually repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238973/discord-bot-unusually-repeats)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code where you add the event listener run multiple times, causing the bot to execute onGuildMessageReceived for every listener when he receive the command.
Would help if you could share more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my case,
when running the bot from VS, you usually re-run it and it opens a new instance of process. That gets to run multiple times (more instances, more repeats).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).